# Timed subscriptions in SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

We are running SQL Server reporting Services. We have multiple timed subscriptions which have now stopped working as the Active Directory user has suddenly been deleted.

Having done some research everything points to updating the owner of the job to a valid AD user, Which then works successfully. However if a new subscription is created we get the old AD user as the Owner.

Apart from manually updating the Job with the new AD user each time the job is created or updated, is there a way to fix this permanently going forward with the new Ad user ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using the credentials of the old AD user in the Reporting Services Configuration Manager Database settings.

Go to `Reporting Services Configuration Manager` select the `Database` tab, in `Current Report Server Database Credential` I recommend you set a Service Account to avoid this issue occur again.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Alejandro. I have just started to configure one from scratch in the test environment.